# Install libSVM-3.17 on Mac OS X 10.9 Mavericks

Tags: macos, matlab, libsvm

I'm trying to install libsvm-3.17 in my macOS10.9 machine.

I read this [tutorial](http://www.mathworks.it/support/solutions/en/data/1-FR6LXJ/index.html?solution=1-FR6LXJ) about the common problem:

> /Applications/MATLAB_R2011b.app/bin/mex: line 305: llvm-gcc-4.2:
>   command not found

but it didn't solve the issue. I still got these errors:

> /Applications/MATLAB_R2012b.app/bin/mex: line 305: llvm-gcc-4.2:
>   command not found
>
> /Applications/MATLAB_R2012b.app/bin/mex: line 1326: llvm-gcc-4.2:
>   command not found
>
> mex: compile of ' "libsvmread.c"' failed.
>
> If make.m fails, please check README about detailed instructions.

Does anybody know if the problem is the fact that I'm using OSX10.9? In this case, any idea about the solution?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this kind of thing is to use one of the popular package managers in OS X, for example I prefer [homebrew](http://brew.sh):

```
$ brew install libsvm
==> Downloading http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/oldfiles/libsvm-3.17.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> make CFLAGS=
==> make lib
  /usr/local/Cellar/libsvm/3.17: 8 files, 240K, built in 9 seconds
$
```

Comment: Do you have Xcode installed and selected (`xcode-select -p`) ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately I got this error  
==> make CFLAGS=-Os -w -pipe -march=native -mmacosx-version-min=10.9
1 error generated.
make: *** [svm-scale] Error 1

Comment: OK - that's good - what version of Xcode ? 5.0.1 ? Also try `brew update` and perhaps `brew doctor` to make sure your homebrew installation is OK and up-to-date.

Comment: OK - well make sure homebrew is OK (see above) and then if that looks good and you still can't build then maybe consider upgrading to Xcode 5, since that seems to work for me.

Comment: Ok well it seems worked! Thanks, but I stupid question, how can I use it in matlab now?

Comment: I'm not a MATLAB expert but I guess you plan to write a MEX file ? In which case you would just link with libsvm.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem. The article in the link fixed it for me. http://chehsunliu.wordpress.com/2013/12/25/install-libsvm-3-17-for-matlab-r2012a-on-mac-os-x-10-9/